# How to read currency symbol in a perl script

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script where we are reading data from a .csv file which is having some different currency symbol . When we are reading that file and write the content I can see it is printing

```
Get <A3>50 or <80>50 daily
```

Actual value is

```
Get £50 or €50 daily
```

With Dollar sign it is working fine if there is any other currency code it is not working

I tried

```perl
open my $in,  '<:encoding(UTF-8)',  'input-file-name'  or die $!;
open my $out, '>:encoding(latin1)', 'output-file-name' or die $!;

while ( <$in> ) {
   print $out $_;
}
```

```
$ od -t x1 input-file-name
0000000 47 65 74 20 c2 a3 35 30 20 6f 72 20 e2 82 ac 35
0000020 30 20 64 61 69 6c 79 0a
0000030
```

od -t x1 output-file-name
0000000 47 65 74 20 a3 35 30 20 6f 72 20 5c 78 7b 32 30
0000020 61 63 7d 35 30 20 64 61 69 6c 79 0a
0000034

but that is also not helping .Output I am getting

```
Get \xA350 or \x8050 daily
```

```
 od -t x1 output-file-name
0000000 47 65 74 20 a3 35 30 20 6f 72 20 5c 78 7b 32 30
0000020 61 63 7d 35 30 20 64 61 69 6c 79 0a
0000034
```

Comment: Is the input encoded in UTF-8? Have you set the encoding of the output, too?

Comment: @choroba Yes i have done that , I have updated the question

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You talk about a database, but "the code you tried" is just opening files.

Comment: @ikegami Right now I am reading one file and writing content to a new file . I have updated the code

Comment: Then provide that code. And can you provide the output of `hexdump -C input-file-name` or `od -t x1 input-file-name`, and the same for `output-file-name`

Comment: od -t x1 input-file-name.txt
0000000 47 65 74 20 c2 a3 35 30 20 6f 72 20 e2 82 ac 35
0000020 30 20 64 61 69 6c 79 0a
0000030

Comment: Smells like windows-1252.

Comment: Yes the files are coming from windows server and we reading it on Unix server

Comment: And `output-file-name`?

Comment: k, gimme a few.

Comment: @ikegami when I am opening the file from vi I can see something like this 
Get <A3>50 or <80>50 daily and i tried dos2unix but that is not helping .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

| Unicode Code Point | Glyph | UTF-8 | Input File | ISO-8859-1 | Output File |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U+00A3 POUND SIGN | £ | C2 A3 | C2 A3 | A3 | A3 |
| U+20AC EURO SIGN | € | E2 82 AC | E2 82 AC | N/A | 5C 78 7B 32 30 61 63 7D |

("LATIN1" is an alias for "ISO-8859-1".)

There are no problems with the input file.

- `£` is correctly encoded in your input file.
- `€` is correctly encoded in your input file.

As for the output file,

- `£` is correctly encoded in your output file.
- `€` isn't found in the [latin1 charset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), so `\x{20ac}` is used instead.

Your program is working as expected.

You say you see `<A3>` instead of `£`. That's probably because the program you are using is expecting a file encoded using UTF-8, but you provided a file encoded using ISO-8859-1.

You also say you see `<80>` instead of `€`. But there's no way you'd see that for the file you provided.

Comment: So how we can the print the correct value in the output file instead of printing encode values

Comment: As the answers says, the correct value is in the output file

Comment: cat output-file-name
Get ▒50 or \x{20ac}50 daily

Comment: This is what I see when i am opening the file

Comment: Yes, that's what you get for printing a latin1 file to a UTF-8 terminal. Again, that's not a problem with the file; that's a problem with what you do with it.

Comment: If you want that to work, create a UTF-8 file instead of a ISO-8859-1 aka LATIN1 file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249018/discussion-between-developer-and-ikegami).